# How to learn a regression if the formula is known, but coefficients are not?

Tags: regression

My goal is to predict delivery cost by distance and client.

Data sample. Known clients are one-hot encoded.

| distance | client_a | client_b | cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 0 | 0 | 130 |
| 15 | 1 | 0 | 180 |
| 12 | 1 | 0 | 153 |
| 18 | 0 | 1 | 184 |
| 15 | 1 | 0 | 180 |
| 20 | 0 | 0 | 250 |
| 12 | 1 | 0 | 153 |
| 16 | 0 | 1 | 168 |
| 10 | 0 | 1 | 120 |
| 13 | 0 | 0 | 180 |

I suppose a formula

$$
cost = (distance \times c_{dist} + c_{fee}) \times (1 - client\_a \times c_a) \times (1 - client\_b \times c_b)
$$
where
$c_{dist}$ - cost per distance unit
$c_{fee}$ - quote fee
$c_a$, $c_b$ - discounts for known clients

The perfect coefficients for the example: $c_{dist} = 10$, $c_{fee} = 50$, $c_a = 0.1$, $c_b = 0.2$.

I see that simple linear model doesn't match the formula.

Which approach can I use to learn $c_{dist}$, $c_{fee}$, $c_a$ and $c_b$ from the data?

Comment: [Please do not cross-post on multiple Stacks.](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/113770/73930) // I’ll always advocate for posting statistics questions on here rather than Data Science, though it’s your call about which question to keep and which to delete.

Comment: I'll delete on Data Science. Thank you!

Comment: The notation is very confusing, because "$c_{client}$" appears to refer to *two* coefficients.  If that's correct, your model *is* a simple linear model.  The four explanatory variables are an intercept, `distance`, the client adjustment variable, and the interaction of the latter two.

Comment: @whuber Agree. I'll clarify the question

Comment: @whuber Take a look now please

Comment: Now it's clearer--and more clearly non-linear.  But there remain many possible approaches.  The choice of procedure depends in part on why and how your data might not perfectly fit this model.  Could you explain how that might come about?  For instance, maybe other unmeasured variables affect the costs; or maybe the distances are only approximately known; *etc.*  It always helps to examine how the data differ from what such a model might predict.

Comment: @whuber, in real data costs were set by humans and coefficients would be good for explainability and retrospective. Yes, there are plenty another features. I use RMSPE as a metric.

Comment: As I suggested before, a good point of departure for identifying an appropriate procedure would be to select a likely procedure, fit the model, and examine the distribution of the residuals.  That will indicate how, if at all, the procedure should be modified.  I would expect (and hope) that the residuals would scale roughly in direction proportion to the estimated costs, rather than being completely random; and if so, that would suggest taking logarithms of both sides in your model and fitting the resulting (simpler, but still non-linear) model.

Comment: @whuber Do you suggest fitting a linear model and then a more complex model from logarithm of residuals? Well, I tried this approach and it worked a little better that a single model. The problem that a linear model gets noisy data because of non-linear features influence.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: given new information. This could possibly be solved with a regular linear model, not exactly with your proposed formula but a simpler one, if this is acceptable:

$$\text{cost}=\text{intercept}+\beta_1 \cdot \text{distance}+\beta_2 \cdot \text{client}$$

where client is a categorical variable. You could also add an interaction term between distance and client, however the provided data is not enough to reliably estimate this as well.

I also coded the "unknown" clients as "x". The results from a linear model are

```
summary(lm(cost~distance+client,data=df))
```

resulting in

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  40.5903     5.3609   7.572 0.000276 ***
distance      9.3266     0.3688  25.291 2.52e-07 ***
clientb     -20.0478     3.0681  -6.534 0.000614 ***
clientx      18.6122     3.0385   6.126 0.000865 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.977 on 6 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9918,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9877 
F-statistic: 241.9 on 3 and 6 DF,  p-value: 1.202e-06
```

**Old answer**

Using general optimization in R and minimizing MSE

```
optim(
  par=c(1,1,1),
  function(c){mean((df$cost-(df$distance*c[2]+c[1])*c[3])^2)}
)

$par
[1] 9.193567 1.725890 5.117081

$value
[1] 230.8635

$counts
function gradient 
     200       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

using the obtained coefficients we get the following predictions

```
cbind("cost"=df$cost,"predicted_cost"=(df$distance*1.725890+9.193567)*5.117081)

      cost predicted_cost
 [1,]  130       117.6964
 [2,]  180       179.5170
 [3,]  153       153.0225
 [4,]  184       206.0116
 [5,]  180       179.5170
 [6,]  250       223.6746
 [7,]  153       153.0225
 [8,]  168       188.3485
 [9,]  120       135.3594
[10,]  180       161.8540
```

Comment: The trouble is that the coefficients will not be unique.

Comment: @Dave Entirely possible. Depends also on OP's goal, inference, prediction, and so on.

Comment: @user2974951 c_client depends on client. I edited the question

Comment: Why do you take this approach when `lm` will give better and more informative results?

Comment: @user2974951 Linear model is not enough. The "client" gives percentage (not absolute) correction.

Answer (score 1):

Inspiring by @user2974951 and @whuber suggestions

I can fix coefficients alternately in the formula

$$
cost = (distance \times c_{dist} + c_{fee}) \times (1 - client\_a \times c_a) \times (1 - client\_b \times c_b)
$$

1. I get a linear model fixing $c_a$ and $c_b$

$$
\dfrac{cost}{client\_corrections} = distance \times c_{dist} + c_{fee}
$$

2. I get a linear-log model fixing $c_{dist}$ and $c_{fee}$

$$
log(\dfrac{cost}{distance\_based\_cost}) = client\_a * correction_a + client\_b * correction_b
$$

Python implementation

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'distance': [8, 15, 12, 18, 15, 20, 12, 16, 10, 13],
    'client_a': [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    'client_b': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    'cost': [130, 180, 153, 184, 180, 250, 153, 168, 120, 180]
})

linear_model = LinearRegression()
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'distance': df['distance'],
    'cost': df['cost']
})
linear_model.fit(df_1.drop('cost', axis=1), df_1['cost'])
c_dist = linear_model.coef_[0]
c_fee = linear_model.intercept_
print(f'''
# Fit linear model fixing "client_a" and "client_b to zero"
c_dist = {c_dist:.06f}
c_fee = {c_fee:.06f}
''')

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'distance_cost_log': np.log(df['distance'] * c_dist + c_fee),
    'client_a_correction': df['client_a'],
    'client_b_correction': df['client_b'],
    'cost_log': np.log(df['cost'])
})
linear_log_model = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)
linear_log_model.fit(df_2.drop('cost_log', axis=1), df_2['cost_log'])
c_a = (1.0 - np.exp(linear_log_model.coef_[1]))
c_b = (1.0 - np.exp(linear_log_model.coef_[2]))
print(f'''
# Fit linear-log model fixing "c_dist" and "c_fee"
c_a = {c_a:.06f}
c_b = {c_b:.06f}
''')

linear_model = LinearRegression()
df_3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'distance': df['distance'],
    'discounted_cost': df['cost'] / (1 - df['client_a'] * c_a) / (1 - df['client_b'] * c_b)
})
linear_model.fit(df_3.drop('discounted_cost', axis=1), df_3['discounted_cost'])
c_dist = linear_model.coef_[0]
c_fee = linear_model.intercept_
print(f'''
# Fit linear model fixing "client_a" and "client_b"
c_dist = {c_dist:.06f}
c_fee = {c_fee:.06f}
''')

df_4 = pd.DataFrame({
    'distance_cost_log': np.log(df['distance'] * c_dist + c_fee),
    'client_a_correction': df['client_a'],
    'client_b_correction': df['client_b'],
    'cost_log': np.log(df['cost'])
})
linear_log_model = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)
linear_log_model.fit(df_4.drop('cost_log', axis=1), df_4['cost_log'])
c_a = (1.0 - np.exp(linear_log_model.coef_[1]))
c_b = (1.0 - np.exp(linear_log_model.coef_[2]))
print(f'''
# Again, fit linear-log model fixing "c_dist" and "c_fee"
c_a = {c_a:.06f}
c_b = {c_b:.06f}
''')
```

Output

```
# Fit linear model fixing "client_a" and "client_b to zero"
c_dist = 8.829268
c_fee = 47.073171


# Fit linear-log model fixing "c_dist" and "c_fee"
c_a = 0.099476
c_b = 0.199846


# Fit linear model fixing "client_a" and "client_b"
c_dist = 9.999716
c_fee = 49.949534


# Again, fit linear-log model fixing "c_dist" and "c_fee"
c_a = 0.100008
c_b = 0.200017
```